# Как собрать, установить и подключить пакеты CMake в одном CMakeLists?

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

Собираю на Android NDK под разные архитектуры. Есть директории с исходниками сторонних библиотек.
У этих библиотек прописаны экспортируемые *-config.cmake, т.е. это именно пакеты, не модули.

Хочется в CMakeLists.txt целевого проекта, чтобы все эти библиотеки собирались из исходников и устанавливались в условную `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`, для того, чтобы их можно было после подключить как CMake пакеты через `find_package()`, вроде:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(native-activity)

# собрать сторонние библиотеки, установить в CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR и указать их в CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
...

find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
find_package(Pixman REQUIRED)
find_package(Cairo REQUIRED)

add_library(native-activity SHARED native-activity.c)
target_link_libraries(native-activity android native_app_glue log pixman cairo)
```

Вариант с `add_subdirectory()` мне не нравится, т.к. некоторые библиотеки могут переиспользовать другие. С пакетами мне кажется более лаконичный вариант, только я не знаю, как заставить CMake их собрать и установить не выходя из основного CMakeLists.txt.
Надеюсь на понимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заставить CMake в процессе обработки `CMakeLists.txt` выполнять "внешние" действие можно с помощью команды [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html):

```
# Директория, куда будут устанавливаться вспомогательные проекты
# Если не хотите "захламлять" CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR,
# то лучше использовать не её, а поддиректорию.
set(SUBPROJECTS_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/subprojects-install")
set(XXX_BUILD_DIRECTORY "<директория для сборки проекта XXX>")
# Создаём директорию для сборки проекта XXX
execute_process(COMMAND mkdir -p "${XXX_BUILD_DIRECTORY}")
# Конфигурируем проект XXX в заданной сборочной директории
# ВАЖНО: последовательные COMMAND должны располагаться в разных execute_process.
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE} "<директория с исходниками XXX>"
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${SUBPROJECTS_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${XXX_BUILD_DIRECTORY}
)
# Собираем проект XXX и устанавливаем его.
execute_process(COMMAND make install
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${XXX_BUILD_DIRECTORY}
)

# ... Аналогично устанавливаем другие проекты

# Добавляем директорию установки проектов в CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH,
# чтобы CMake искал их в find_package
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SUBPROJECTS_INSTALL_DIRECTORY})

# Теперь можно искать установленные проекты
find_package(XXX REQUIRED)
```

Запускать много разных команд через `execute_process` может показаться неудобным. (И это еще не проверяются возможные ошибки при сборке и установке других проектов).

Можно написать скрипт установки на любом другом языке (например, на bash), и вызывать этот скрипт с помощью одного `execute_process`.

Comment: Благодарю. Ответ немного запоздалый, но я пришел к тому же решению. Похоже, что на данный момент это единственный верный способ реализовать подобное в CMake.